# Where does a Nigerian submit a visa application for the Bahamas?

Tags: visas, nigerian-citizens, embassies, bahamas

How do you submit your Bahamas visa application from Nigeria? I’m a Nigerian and I have been having issues submitting the application because there is no [Bahamian embassy or consulate](http://mofa.gov.bs/diplomatic-relations/bahamas-overseas-offices/embassies/) in Nigeria, and the British High Commission here handles some consular matters for the Bahamas, but they said they don’t accept applications for Bahamas visas.

Comment: A visa interview for the Bahamas? I’ve never heard of that but I’ll ask around. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I misinterpreted something on the website, so I've removed that comment. At worst, you can contact their Ministry of Foreign Affairs directly; they have contact information on the back of their informational [brochure](http://mofa.gov.bs/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/CONSULAR-BROCHURE-UPDATED-MARCH.pdf). The telephone country code for the Bahamas is +1.

Comment: http://mofa.gov.bs/consular-services/visitors-visa/  I think you are out of luck. You need to go to a consulate, but none (consulate embassies) and near you.

Comment: A Nigerian just asked how they could get to the Bahamas without transit. I’ll ask how they were able to make it happen.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi perhaps point 4 on the page you link to is an exception to point 3.  Or is a personal visit required by both the sponsor and the applicant in such cases?

Comment: @phoog. So why’s it everywhere online that you can apply at the British embassy while the embassy is saying something different.

Comment: @user87882 where is it online that you can apply at the British embassy?  I haven't seen that.  And does "British embassy" mean the British high commission in Nigeria, or the Bahamian high commission in the UK?

Comment: Trying to add a URL but it’s saying too much but this is from this official website ....  bahamas.gov.bs.

Comment: Applicants applying for a visa at the British embassy must submit the application at least 4 weeks prior to travel”

Comment: @user87882 yes, I see that.  The URL is crazy!  What are they doing, encoding the entire page content into the URL?  I will post another answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know, [applying for a Bahamas visa](http://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/gov/government/services/!ut/p/b1/vZTZcuI4GIWfJQ9ALHn3pbzgfV_AvnEZvAIGjB1j_PRNulI1M3QlzEUn0pVK59fR-bRgCbbGkmM2NlU2NKdjdngfJ3RKANlEiGRNmQI0UEPHQA6j4KwF74L4LgCfNAS-qrd1_KP-MwEJnvmvsLUSXyexNysJ-am7tzUVMfG5v86MEDdbTTBMgUe-c-BCvUuOK4O6hYtN8XYYywM_JeUC2OtIPbrd9oLatvVqrZovrttZzbzk9VRW9cnOdZE_xr202FjKtVjWDnK3tpv2bw3JlrnNHOJxlrQF2-2HegxuoJ_y3KnGIKuivhjT0iGRVx4PNnp5kvcO5Hde2TZd4T7N0iQHVBhYqig5hBzQf9QbiLoLbMog9CV0_f9b_7ngKe_kyyN9P7Hfgq-uxMMKDxngMwH-ZA93ipZyagssvsuYf2Qsrb2H1W3d4HRCMXEswNaATP3d7azO-9nbMS4wwaQHOxVACcBhJ4bWRgKWZUPfMK9wDqdBqoAPoG3t-yngAiePvJBHiCFzono0tPHg3VCAtB5SwMeZ7zZ8TEj8sKFEfjtSHSfuhgZhWKwAgcv8sCH99xNqWNJs2tfrtn0FrxxDAxYAjqUAxCmCwaJdTHNir14l1SrrIpKLXTFHYXOtNBSHdiuAWjudnZu31sYbd3Irfhe3JRMr8tSzIjsteNcPw-4cJvSlkDMxyfg3vlT49UkfqmvIjtX6fFxFF3noRRNH4iBSo7E4m2KXzbzfUJO48WCYZm0ubKOlPzDGzV156T6OEnE0mrQuYeEzulomZl2OqO9zK5sAfSHUqgr6ciXU9OpmkaWV06nLTEyXRUWKxMa5JPuXR9hyEIE7bIA8H7qA9cAfsGfP9mdp8vfkDOdIGwIxsDZL0xoKaEmnGwxCOEiT5TOWGYgh9DnlA7YQagmJP3mhgPpuQ5my2ftXxQQOonAABOKHDf2_j_Q_95dgIYdzANAUTUOOZLHIiG-MeDKvIuJTzZ2KvsgXwto_g1pE4YHSLyhYKN3Y5fp2I9b5NqCUG6rULGZndrdxDKlodDVYVeFoysOynbb11qEU1T9eg9Jh9tKSFmKOXaSIkW9ax7XuLFqQZWyari-6sN4eET1TeNfT-RRDzV1d56UlznZmVNILdm7DcNR1g_Ykj7XKf3Xq8tGrXywOGUw!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) requires a visit in person to an embassy or consulate.

There is a [Bahamas embassy in Haiti](http://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/diplomatic%20relations/overseas%20missions/overseas%20missions/!ut/p/b1/vZTbkqo4GIWfpR_AJgEC4RIFOQchQcQbCxVQ8NjScnj6Tc_sqZlxardzsbuTq1Stxcdaf4BbcgtueUrv-yKt9-dTevg4L6WVYPheMBGxhyVRARZkxNL0mWAwaRAkgwD8YqngTz8wPFUd_AYCErCimavOZJP3Hf6n_1cC8VM_JpCLucU2AbJ28wpdp3fxnNBbOF63x9hPWB7iotp5OwVFGzEPLspVIZJHfCvYYb6uL3lipKzLyZ4e8YgEWYuW25ERFuku164nsD4kPXKakNXb1Xu79EpT1DZFyWhFV3Njb8LEE05HxwpGHUgOyv0Kr7HYV3rRN3H2TixYToPUpFc5cI19TPN6tDqN-TINXl6e5B6KeZL70e-qaBiMj1zBmcKA8v9vbp8AnvhjbvnpaD8m94fgs6vx8ISHDPCZgH_yDkOLxDwfMy4ZZPLfMizZH2kc33EVRzA9nmPcAogrWnYXq6_6sOyDlpRZR3TQQS0CVHMDsjaaGwkJ0QselFFDS9p52tYjFfS82p1t52E0VieKW9mzR6DPsw_gBEpOhADl5a8GPiYUvhmoi19eqcMLA9AVXIInEATyNwOl35_Q5pb79fG12RxfwasiSwADoGAEII8EmZuXidhqN6vR9PgOblFZxht-W4jB-34isPhY2ZZIAWLrCi5vU-t04fEoXh1IKsRpmKmJ7joxqO953YxRo1BUNfZOHI9bm07lcEi4adUwFJh0O5e0QKPTSEwm_LK4GNuqUzUoX-V7vk4dUjLeMe3dYVHJmSNTfd2decHPFVUqV7Pkft4skX9N_aBCxnmU8ZlJrQOeH0B1jDDPnB5USU_HWMi7ibDo2lu_F4T9Y9kGm4OhbKCGFAYAh-C_ZYc-7fWWVmIP-7ldM42R9dQjdQaJfu4gi2Ctt4TKxGNaBKli_lV2ZC9F_skXCtBXAw3k4-FXJbOZingAJsI3A-nvr_Rf91fAUOEVACQkSVARMTd3k07Wzl6jqeOVHbTZLduOJgt6ATtNjQ7IeVPZyLzer1tns9Z22w1DZqcWVprgHpfrmatne8dicRHdPaOeHtvNbjNDpkVPDctncqVPpUmi4NFKlY3OvirHoNcIxLIvSbs3Z7LYnFSpR_z1Jm3bBNpB3PRTovV-6hb6C3c5RtHdcVwp1ENM8n9s9PZzFz8AtCfNHg!!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/), and Nigerian nationals can [enter Haiti visa-free](http://www.haiti.org/visa-entry-requirements-for-haiti/) for a visit up to 3 months. (Transiting there through an airport might still need a transit visa from some country though.)

That embassy is located at:

Embassy of the Commonwealth of The Bahamas
12 Rue Goulard
Place Boyer
Pétion-Ville, Haiti
+509 257-8782

Whether this is actually practical for you to visit Haiti to obtain the Bahamas visa, I cannot say. You might simply take a holiday in Haiti instead?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the page linked in the question indicates embassies and high commissions only in Canada, China, Cuba, Haiti, the UK, and the US.  The consulates general are all in the US. (The page http://mofa.gov.bs/consular-services/visitors-visa/ also implies that a visa application might be possible at the mission to the UN in Geneva.)  Haiti is the *only* country with Bahamian diplomatic representation where Nigerian citizens can visit without a visa.

Answer (score 2):

As you brought to my attention, the Bahamian government page [Applying for a Visitor Visa](https://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/Consular%20Services/Visitor%20Visa/!ut/p/b1/vZPZjpswFEC_JR-QwWYx-JGwhTUshgReEJOwB0IWIMnXN6NWajVS25dOfZ8sHfnoXMlUQu2opM-musxu9anPjh_3BKWMtrE9iRVsAbEY6JA4uqy4jEYQtaV26_iBpas-q3pUDOGkteZIDyvaOhk2KykmHxiXHOqVE_TWTWAmAxsgbapLlInODauZXDoTFprL2ltVeqnlXamSencVIT8-d2BSTinPdpGH7ZHP4xW5Y1z55E48SXXxmFyV5AqxtD-8u1m_mh0JAAN1_f16zLTHIdk4XdV34hLq9SGkJx4VQmBu8vAVFr_CwG-OCP7enXxHgGaL4gvRLJF7IRvOYkwVegH9A_iDIn4B_M8XBGR8SMyNaWGTWds0RagdYNOgeQz6s336DZiftnIGtixC2ESu3TLEIapLHFu1bwawItdp53sgKzAIHwzBa_ug-uFqyZiz7C0Wn4UbmnwIJYjMkAMBzX-18HMh85-FCvvlKzVp5iW0GMsRJAg8_j8L0b8vNKikfu_e5n33Bt4wj4AAABY4AGmO4amoiRGWX79f1v2i2ofNbZvTUtluFdEOpCP0ujKG4YTCUYFcjsyHbilzUWQHjlzDfLVM2JnVzwYJOoeFZlOX96gryq1uilgst4V-yWoxcrXJpU1GnutafA6FHKepX4b3ozAMu9ELUXXpx_dpdw4TdCXGeCEXxx8nlHbbmR0U-riyrRRV5MA9m3PkTkqrNtnj3DF-u00Ge4r9fd_Aqeo9VyN1rvPKEgrZbXluy9ainPWpy6mhmyzkC_CXYUpxsfgGwuYqUg!!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) suggests that British diplomatic missions will process Bahamian visa applications:

> Deadline
>
> Visa applications should be submitted at least two weeks before travel. *Applicants applying for a visa at a British Embassy must submit the application at least four weeks prior to travel.*
>
> Related Fee(s)
>
> The following fees apply for visas obtained at The Bahamas’ Embassies and Consulates.  *Prices may vary for Bahamian visas obtained at the British Embassies.*
>
> ...

(emphasis added)

Also, at [Entering the Bahamas](http://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/Landing/Entry%20and%20Departure/!ut/p/b1/vZHJcqMwFEW_pT_AQcxmKYMZzGhms3EBDhSDMDYzXx873YuuVKWz6URaqepI590rLMJCLGriscjjvrg2cf08R8yZlEz9yFNbfctQHFBw11CEvUVKLvkATk8ASDqE78DhCaimqnEqKTH0V_cDLJTT1eA7ZdpDN_c3VT3TsPYP3escXxWnO_d2otE6UEnFS3b9mgHD0mddUoKOkZylNnTBZMtNKKY3N78Jkma4KkOckmkZ1DVbUJAkbdu1upDbfHhGtxal-6bZdsjM4yJzjpeGdDuJQE4hRoZMZKl6wRfB5qjYViiHe0xTHcixs4JepHpGztjRLlLmT27wyYLg69zRb-ST5nDqC-BZ7TvwjxlOD4D97AXZojEXCwF1dsqlVdZqtUswa_pdBf0-X3APAGc_OoZXm05_MPRSmQDrK_oKF3d9_EFVrc7Fsi6-7e0gjK93afgoNAn3KeRxRvVo4Byp7xZ-SEj_uBD_9kpVgnwINVIztjwOSOKnhf8_4QGLigS9TCl6AS8Mx5EMoB8ejgFbnMD80mNY4XqAe2vyUYHXPXtar120P5Kjg6BhDiebpcWc2si91WvOhNrmskJdJMsWjZPHF6WMhjKiqWk9JvKVhVaTB7dd0A2uqDKCFPhx0Pn3w8oX8D6E8zie0zx0-ZPoF3ZYSea9ap3E3Gi9ShAlsxPaRKiKwBfTuzZJhrJkZVar5W0KsxubwaEzJ7dsghHNx2o98X7NzX0vA0o0OF4UtmoXbYdhvvCkbgHMkK_oFWuRN2qMLa_hX_sV_noDHmpvLg!!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/):

> The Bahamas is a major tourist destination, so we make every effort to keep visitors’ Immigration formalities to a minimum.  However, entry requirements do vary from country to country, so nationals of non-Commonwealth countries should enquire at the nearest *British Consulate* or Bahamian Embassy for information on these.

(emphasis added)

If I were you, I would note the exact words the British high commission used when they "said they don’t accept applications for Bahamas visas."  If you have it in writing, so much the better.  Then send an e-mail message to the address found at the bottom of [Applying for a Visitor Visa](https://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/Consular%20Services/Visitor%20Visa/!ut/p/b1/vZPZjpswFEC_JR-QwWYx-JGwhTUshgReEJOwB0IWIMnXN6NWajVS25dOfZ8sHfnoXMlUQu2opM-musxu9anPjh_3BKWMtrE9iRVsAbEY6JA4uqy4jEYQtaV26_iBpas-q3pUDOGkteZIDyvaOhk2KykmHxiXHOqVE_TWTWAmAxsgbapLlInODauZXDoTFprL2ltVeqnlXamSencVIT8-d2BSTinPdpGH7ZHP4xW5Y1z55E48SXXxmFyV5AqxtD-8u1m_mh0JAAN1_f16zLTHIdk4XdV34hLq9SGkJx4VQmBu8vAVFr_CwG-OCP7enXxHgGaL4gvRLJF7IRvOYkwVegH9A_iDIn4B_M8XBGR8SMyNaWGTWds0RagdYNOgeQz6s336DZiftnIGtixC2ESu3TLEIapLHFu1bwawItdp53sgKzAIHwzBa_ug-uFqyZiz7C0Wn4UbmnwIJYjMkAMBzX-18HMh85-FCvvlKzVp5iW0GMsRJAg8_j8L0b8vNKikfu_e5n33Bt4wj4AAABY4AGmO4amoiRGWX79f1v2i2ofNbZvTUtluFdEOpCP0ujKG4YTCUYFcjsyHbilzUWQHjlzDfLVM2JnVzwYJOoeFZlOX96gryq1uilgst4V-yWoxcrXJpU1GnutafA6FHKepX4b3ozAMu9ELUXXpx_dpdw4TdCXGeCEXxx8nlHbbmR0U-riyrRRV5MA9m3PkTkqrNtnj3DF-u00Ge4r9fd_Aqeo9VyN1rvPKEgrZbXluy9ainPWpy6mhmyzkC_CXYUpxsfgGwuYqUg!!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) under "For more information please contact."  The first address is for "The Bahamas Consulate Division" in Nassau.  Explain that their website instructs you to apply at the British high commission, and that the British high commission said that they don't accept such applications, and ask them what to do.

Once you have the answer, please come back here to [post it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) so others know what you found.

Comment: Yes, I realize that I should probably have said "ask the Bahamian government" in a comment rather than an answer, but since the relevant URLs are ***over 900 characters long,*** that was not possible.  It's possible that the huge string of characters is session dependent, but I could not figure out how to shorten the URLs in such a way that they still pointed to the same pages.

Comment: I just sent them an email. I had sent emails to the British Consulate in Nigeria/London previously but they haven’t replied my email.

Answer (score -2):

Just apply at the Bahamian Embassy in London if you have a valid UK visa. Thats what i plan to do. Won't advise anyone to apply directly at the British Embassy. Notice there are many cruises and tours that start from UK to the Bahamas. Going to Haiti might be expensive. What do you if you don't get a visa.

Comment: You assume OP has a UK visa and is in a position to apply in the UK or at the embassy in London from Nigeria. It looks like you do not understand the question as asked and your answer seems not to fit the question. Can you please edit and include how someone from Nigeria can apply in London?