# Applying for Commonwealth Countries Visa through UK embassy

Tags: visas, applications, bahamas

I am visiting the Bahamas for a holiday. Since the Bahamas is part of Commonwealth countries. I was told that I could apply for a Bahamas Visa on Visa4Uk site, as there's an option to apply for Commonwealth countries' Visas.
However, I can't find that option. I think it's because the Visa4Uk site has just been updated. 
Can anyone suggest another way to apply through the UK embassy?

Comment: Welcome! What country are you applying from?

Comment: Who told you about that option? A quick check of the official Bahamas website doesn’t mention it as far as I can see http://www.bahamas.gov.bs Also see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131080/where-does-a-nigerian-submit-a-visa-application-for-the-bahamas

Answer (score 3):

This https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/apply-for-a-british-overseas-territory-or-commonwealth-country-visa/apply-for-a-visa-if-you-want-to-travel-to-a-british-overseas-territory-or-commonwealth-country seems to provide the answer.

How to apply

If you are travelling to one of the 6 British Overseas Territories or 3 Commonwealth countries listed, and there is no local representation to apply for your visa, you must complete and submit a UK visa application form online and select the reason for visit as ‘other’ and the visa type as ‘Overseas Territory & Commonwealth’ to proceed. https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply